# Minimum of summed sequence

Tags: inequality, optimization

Define M non-negative sequences, 
\begin{equation}
a_{m,1}\geq a_{m,2}\geq,...,\geq a_{m,K}\quad \text{for}\ m=1,..,M
\end{equation}
and cyclic shifted versions $a^{\zeta_m}_{m,k}$ with shift value $\zeta_m\in [0,K]$ that
\begin{equation}
[a^{\zeta_m}_{m,1},a^{\zeta_m}_{m,2},...,a^{\zeta_m}_{m,K}]=[a_{m,\zeta_m+1},a_{m,\zeta_m+2},...,a_{m,K},a_{m,1},...,a_{m,\zeta_m}].
\end{equation}
Given 
\begin{equation}
Y_{m^o}=\sum^K_{k=1}\frac{a_{m^o,k}^{\zeta_{m^o}}\cdot\sum^M_{m\neq m^o}a_{m,k}^{\zeta_{m}}}{\sum^M_{m=1}a_{m,k}^{\zeta_{m}}},
\end{equation}

### what is the minimum of $Y_{m^o}$ and $\sum^M_{m^o=1}Y_{m^o}$?

-

My tried idea is letting
\begin{equation}
b_k = \sum^M_{m=1}a_{m,k}^{\zeta_{m}}
\end{equation}
then
\begin{eqnarray}
Y_{m^o} 
&=& \sum^K_{k=1} \frac{a_{m^o,k}^{\zeta_{m^o}}\cdot (b_k-a_{m^o,k}^{\zeta_{m^o}})}{b_k}\\
&=& \underbrace{\sum^K_{k=1} a_{m^o,k}^{\zeta_{m^o}}}_{(1)} - \underbrace{\sum^K_{k=1} (a_{m^o,k}^{\zeta_{m^o}})^2\cdot \frac{1}{b_k}}_{(2)}
\end{eqnarray}

(1) is fixed with the given $a_{m,k}$ for $k=1,...,K$, then using rearrangement inequality to prove 
\begin{equation}
(2) \leq X_{m^o}
\end{equation}
then 
\begin{equation}
Y_{m^o} \geq (1)-X_{m^o}
\end{equation}

However, I don't know how to finish it.

To the minimum of $\sum^M_{m^o=1}Y_{m^o}$, I suppose it is reached when $b_1=b_2=\cdots=b_K$. Is that right?

Comment: What are the variables in your problem?

Comment: the shift value. what is the optimal shift values to achieve the minimum.